# How to change Firefox web driver proxy settings at runtime?

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, selenium-firefoxdriver

I use Selenium 2.35.0 and configure proxy settings like:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyStr).setFtpProxy(proxyStr).setSslProxy(proxyStr);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefox, profile, cap);
```

When I need to change proxy settings I force to restart webdriver and speify other "proxyStr".

How I can reach this changing without of webdriver restart?

Comment: you can try - `RemoteWebDriver#getCapabilities()` and the cast  `Capabilities` object it to `DesiredCapabilities` and set your new proxy to `DesiredCapabilities#setCapability`, load the url

Comment: I didn't use RemoteWebDriver. I use WebDriver.

Comment: RemoteWebDriver is parent class of WebDriver my friend

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you set a proxy for any given driver, it is set only at the time WebDriver session is created; it cannot be changed at runtime. Even if you get the capabilities of the created session, you won't be able to change it. So the answer is, no, you must start a new session if you want to use different proxy settings.