# Change proxy after starting chromedriver in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, webdriver

Is it possible to use proxy after starting chromedriver on the same browser?

EX:

1. I start chrome driver
2. Load website
3. Put in info
4. Use proxy
5. Click submit

I think i found some ways to do it in python and JS but im not sure how to convert it to java

Answer (score 3):

As per [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s current implementation once you configure the WebDriver instance with the required **Options** and **Capabilities** and initialize the *WebDriver* session to open a *Web Browser*, you cannot change the capabilities runtime. Even if you are able to retrieve the runtime capabilities still you won't be able to change them back.

So, in-order to use a **proxy** you have to initiate a new *WebDriver* session.

here is @JimEvans [clear and concise comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565426/how-to-change-firefox-web-driver-proxy-settings-in-runtime) (as of Oct 24 '13 at 13:02) related to proxy settings capability:

> When you set a proxy for any given driver, it is set only at the time WebDriver session is created; it cannot be changed at runtime. Even if you get the capabilities of the created session, you won't be able to change it. So the answer is, no, you must start a new session if you want to use different proxy settings.

You can find a relevant discussion in [Set capability on already running selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224348/set-capability-on-already-running-selenium-webdriver/46232538#46232538)

Answer (score -1):

You can use ChromeOptions class.

```
You can create an instance of ChromeOptions, which has convenient methods for setting ChromeDriver-specific capabilities. You can then pass the ChromeOptions 

object into the ChromeDriver constructor:
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);



ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
// Add the WebDriver proxy capability.
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("myhttpproxy:3337");
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

// Add a ChromeDriver-specific capability.
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but doesnt that open a new browser? i want to continue on the same driver and page because when i click submit website checks ip and  if its been used they ban it and i only need to use proxy when clicking on submit but if i start the driver with proxy it runs through 10Mb of data per task so if im able to use proxy right before clicking submit then it saves a lot of data.