# Switch proxy without closing webdriver python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to change the proxy ip address for your Selenium Chrome web driver without closing the browser and just by reloading?

I know that you can add a proxy by running this but how can you change it?:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: You can't change it but you can workaround by having a proxy that switches upstream proxies.

Comment: @ProgrammingManiac Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177973/change-proxy-after-starting-chromedriver-in-java-selenium/58182525#58182525) helps you?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.