# Can I run Selenium using geckodriver without a webpage detecting marionette?

Tags: java, selenium, marionette, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

I want to use FirefoxDriver with Selenium but I keep getting detected by webpages. When I add the following code

```html
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "../../../../../../../usr/bin/geckodriver");
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.setCapability("marionette", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
```

The webpages cant't detect I'm using geckodriver but I can't use Selenium automation and that's my problem. I need the automation without detection.

QUESTIONS:

1. Can I change the setCapabilites on/off while the driver is running?
2. Is it easier to do this using ChromeDriver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *FirefoxDriver* with *Selenium* but getting detected is quite common now as:

> **Selenium identifies itself**

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to make Selenium script undetectable using GeckoDriver and Firefox through Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873022/how-to-make-selenium-script-undetectable-using-geckodriver-and-firefox-through-p/58879076#58879076)

---

### Marionette

As per the documentation, [Marionette](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/marionette/Intro.html#introduction-to-marionette),  is the automation driver for Mozilla’s Gecko engine. It can remotely control the UI and the internal JavaScript of a Gecko platform, such as Mozilla Firefox. It can control both the *chrome* (i.e. menus and functions) or the content (the webpage loaded inside the browsing context), giving a high level of control and ability to replicate user actions. In addition to performing actions on the browser, Marionette can also read the properties and attributes of the DOM. Now, [marionette](/questions/tagged/marionette) shares much of the same API as [Selenium/WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491), with additional commands to interact with Gecko’s chrome interface. Its goal is to replicate what Selenium does for web content, i.e. *to enable the tester to have the ability to send commands to remotely control a user agent*.

We have also discussed in details about **Why Firefox requires GeckoDriver?** within this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver/43661697#43661697)

Finally, in the discussion [Difference between webdriver.firefox.marionette & webdriver.gecko.driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272919/difference-between-webdriver-firefox-marionette-webdriver-gecko-driver/43920453#43920453) we discussed about initializing *Firefox* sessions using *legacy Firefox 47.x browsers* and *GeckoDriver* enabled Firefox >47.x browsers. The conclusion was when using Firefox browsers > v77.x you have to mandatorily use *GeckoDriver* which extensively uses the **marionette**. So configuring **`marionette`** as **`false`** won't help us out. While using the latest version of [geckodriver](/questions/tagged/geckodriver), [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox), you have to use the **marionette** by default.

If you still want to initialise a *Firefox* browsing session without using **marionette** you need to configure **`"marionette"`** to **`false`** as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://path//to//geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability("marionatte", false);
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.merge(dc);
FirefoxDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
System.out.println("Application opened");
System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities while initiating Firefox v37 through Selenium v3.11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789963/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of/49791342#49791342)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with Firefox 46 through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782650/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a/47785513#47785513)
- [How can Geckodriver/Firefox work without Marionette? (running python selenium 3 against FF 53)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530302/how-can-geckodriver-firefox-work-without-marionette-running-python-selenium-3/44537094#44537094)

---

The other questions:

- *Can I change the setCapabilites on/off while the driver is running?*: The short answer is **No**, you can't change the capabilites while the session initiated by the webdriver is **`In Progress`** and you can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

  - [Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023853/change-chromeoptions-in-an-existing-webdriver/53025100#53025100)
  - [Set capability on already running selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224348/set-capability-on-already-running-selenium-webdriver/46232538#46232538)
- *Is it easier to do this using ChromeDriver?*: Again the precise answer is **No**, **ChromeDriver** also gets detected and you can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

  - [Is there a version of selenium that is not detectable ? can selenium be truly undetectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528631/is-there-a-version-of-selenium-that-is-not-detectable-can-selenium-be-truly-un/56529616#56529616)
  - [Webpage Is Detecting Selenium Webdriver with Chromedriver as a bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984185/webpage-is-detecting-selenium-webdriver-with-chromedriver-as-a-bot/54984891#54984891)

---

### Outro

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403)