# Changing Proxy Settings without Closing the Driver in Selenium/Splinter

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, splinter

In an older version of Splinter/Selenium [this was said not to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565426/how-to-change-firefox-web-driver-proxy-settings-at-runtime). This answer a few years later claims it [is possible with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776607/python-selenium-webdriver-changing-proxy-settings-on-the-fly), but this code doens't work for me (I might have just failed to translate it to Python). [This answer closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python/38168865#38168865) the browser and then re-opens it, and I need the window/browser to stay open.

With plugins like FoxyProxy, its very easy to change the proxy on-the-fly, but I don't think Selenium can interact with plugins because they are page elements?

As Splinter is designed to be a less verbose wrapper for Selenium, it would be awesome if there was an easy way to accomplish this. That being said, any hack to just have this functionality would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the translated version you have used? Please post that code

Comment: Any feedback on the answer I posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use it like below

```
browser.visit("about:config")

script = """
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
.getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);

prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.type", 1);
prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.http", "{0}");
prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port", "{1}");
prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.ssl", "{0}");
prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.ssl_port", "{1}");
prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.ftp", "{0}");
prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.ftp_port", "{1}");
"""

browser.execute_script(script.format("ProxyIP", "PORT"))
```

PS: Credits to [Python Selenium Webdriver - Changing proxy settings on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776607/python-selenium-webdriver-changing-proxy-settings-on-the-fly?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776607/python-selenium-webdriver-changing-proxy-settings-on-the-fly?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, thanks should have done that earlier only don't how I missed. Had upvoted the answer but forgot to credit the same