# Python and selenium: how to change Firefox's profile multiple times

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I set up Firefox's profile and launched the driver with that profile, after that, I want to know how to change some preferences on that profile multiple times, or how to change the profile after launching the driver? here is my code for setting up the profile:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'D:\\Workspace\\Res')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "application/x-7z-compressed")


driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, executable_path=r"C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the current implementation of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) once you configure the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance with the required *Options* and *Capabilities* and initialize the *Web Browser* session to open a *Browsing Context*, you cannot change the capabilities runtime. Even if you are able to retrieve the runtime capabilities still you won't be able to change them back.

So, in-order to change the [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) *User Profile* you have to initiate a new *WebDriver* session.

---

### Reference

Here is @JimEvans [clear and concise comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565426/how-to-change-firefox-web-driver-proxy-settings-in-runtime) (as of Oct 24 '13 at 13:02) related to proxy settings capability:

> When you set a proxy for any given driver, it is set only at the time WebDriver session is created; it cannot be changed at runtime. Even if you get the capabilities of the created session, you won't be able to change it. So the answer is, no, you must start a new session if you want to use different proxy settings.

---

### Outro

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to set selenium webdriver from headless mode to normal mode within the same session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721676/how-to-set-selenium-webdriver-from-headless-mode-to-normal-mode-within-the-same/54722252#54722252)